# Testing multiple connections to socket.io server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to write a test for my socket.io server app. This test should create some number of connections (10 e.g.) and then every client should send a message to server every 2 seconds. Here's what I did:

```
var numberOfSockets = 10;
var instruction = "test";

for (var id = 1; id <= numberOfSockets; id++)
{
    var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000');
    var logPassData = {"login":id, "pass":id, "serverClient":"client"};
    socket.emit('logPass', logPassData);
    newFuncTEST(waitTEST);
}

newFuncTEST(waitTEST);

function waitTEST(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        newFuncTEST(waitTEST);
    }, 2000);
}
function newFuncTEST(callback){
    socket.emit('instruction', instruction);
    callback();
}
```

Log file:

```
23:1:12  9 (Client) logged in.
23:1:12  1 (Client) logged in.
23:1:12  2 (Client) logged in.
23:1:12  9 sent instruction: test.
23:1:12  1 sent instruction: test.
23:1:12  3 (Client) logged in.
23:1:12  2 sent instruction: test.
23:1:12  4 (Client) logged in.
23:1:12  3 sent instruction: test.
23:1:12  5 (Client) logged in.
23:1:12  4 sent instruction: test.
23:1:12  6 (Client) logged in.
23:1:12  5 sent instruction: test.
23:1:12  10 (Client) logged in.
23:1:12  6 sent instruction: test.
23:1:12  7 (Client) logged in.
23:1:12  10 sent instruction: test.
23:1:12  10 sent instruction: test.
23:1:12  8 (Client) logged in.
23:1:12  7 sent instruction: test.
23:1:12  8 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  10 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  10 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  10 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  10 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  10 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  10 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  10 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  10 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  10 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  10 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  10 sent instruction: test.
```

I don't know why client only with id=10 sends instructions after some time. There are 11 instructions every 2 seconds all from 10th socket. Why and how to change it to:

```
23:1:14  1 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  2 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  3 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  4 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  5 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  6 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  7 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  8 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  9 sent instruction: test.
23:1:14  10 sent instruction: test.
```

Comment: Because you are overriding socket reference every time in the loop. I'm also not sure how it does not complain about undefined `socket` in function to emit data.

Comment: @HarryJoy Ok, thanks! Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: @Tryam You hold the sockets inside of an array and access each one of them by id.

Comment: Or use the new ES 6 feature **let instead of var**

Comment: Actually, now I know why it allows you to access `socket` in function even if it's defined only in for loop. It's due to variable hoisting in javascript.

Comment: @ahitt6345 Thanks! You really helped me!

Comment: @Harry Joy: a for loop is not a closure. Socket is a part of the window scope. socket==window.scope

Answer (score 0):

You're facing one of the main scoping problems in javascript:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  var a=i;
  setTimeout(()=>{alert(a);},2000);
}
```

This will output: 10,10,10...
Because `a` is overridden every time the loop runs. That's why you should use let. It creates a new variable each time the loop runs, which solves your problem:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  let a=i;
  setTimeout(()=>{alert(a);},2000);
}
```

In your code:

```
let socket=...;
```

To create 10 different sockets instead of overriding one each time...
And for sure you have to keep the scope. You lose it when calling another function. I recommend you to shorten your code:

```
for(){
  let socket=...;
  setInterval(()=>{socket.emit()},2000);
}
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations, let not supported outside strict mode

Comment: I solved my problem using an array of sockets. But also thanks for your help. I understood scope in js.